# Grunt - uglify is not working for all js file with different folder condition

Tags: gruntjs

I want all js file from **dev-> js** folder and **dev->bootstrap->js** should minify to **build-> js** folder and **build->bootstrap->js**

I am trying to use following code but this is not working

```html
uglify: {
   build: {
  files: [{
   expand: true,
   src: '**/*.js',
   dest: ['build/js', 'build/lib/bootstrap/js'],
   cwd: ['dev/js', 'dev/lib/bootstrap/js']
  }]
   }
 }
```

**Error coming as -**

```html
$ grunt
Running "uglify:build" (uglify) task
Warning: Path must be a string. Received [ 'dev/js', 'dev/lib/bootstrap/js' ] Us                   e --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

```html
<pre>

// incoming

dev
  |js
  |lib
    |bootstrap
             |js


// output

build
  |js
  |lib
    |bootstrap
             |js

</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the grunt documentation for [building the files object dynamically](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically), you will find the following definitions:

> `dest` Destination path prefix.
>
> `cwd` All `src` matches are relative to (but don't include) this path.

This is telling us that `dest` must be a string, *not* an array, and it must be the folder under which all compiled files will go. In your example, this is the build/ folder.

Secondly, it tells us that `cwd` is a string indicating the folder under which all source files are to be found. Additionally, it tells us that the src file paths *will not* include this folder prefix when they are mapped to dest file paths. In your example, all source files are relative to the dev/ folder.

Your grunt configuration for your uglify:build task should be updated as follows:

```
files: [{
    expand: true,
    cwd: 'dev/',
    src: '**/*.js',
    dest: 'build/'
}]
```